# Random Srting In Middle of HTML

Tags: php

Hi I need a randomString to Create User Key

```
<?php
function generateRandomString($length = 32) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdef';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}

generateRandomString();
?>
```

This is the URL where people access with the random string
http://www.mypage.com/index.php?User_key=generateRandomString()&User=6487592&User_type=0

Where generateRandomString() is unique for every refresh. Is there any way I can do this?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

The best way to generate a random string is to use a hashing function. PHP has hash: http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php.

The value you pass to the hash can be the current time, so it's always random:

`hash('md5', time()) // "723ee904fd6de114fd11c1b13f6de3f5"`

So your function would look like:

```
<?php
function generateRandomString() {

  return hash('md5', time());
}

generateRandomString();
?>
```

Comment: How to insert in middle of HTML.  http://www.mypage.com/index.php?User_key=generateRandomString()&User=6487592&User_type=0

Comment: if you wanted to create a unique link, for instance, you could do something like: `<a href="/http://www.mypage.com/index.php?User_key=<?= generateRandomString(); ?>">click me</a>`. That will create a link that looks like `http://www.mypage.com/index.php?User_key=723ee904fd6de114fd11c1b13f6de3f5"`

Comment: What abt this part?   "&User=6487592&User_type=0"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate a random no yourself you can use the following code:

```
function random_str($length, $keyspace = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')
    {
        $str = '';
        $max = mb_strlen($keyspace, '8bit') - 1;
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; ++$i) {
            $str .= $keyspace[mt_rand(0, $max)];
        }
        return $str;
    }
    echo random_str(5);//input digits required in random no
```

**eg**: this will give you a 5 digit random no.

Answer (score 0):

Try generating it using this line of code

```
 function generateRandomString($userID){
    return md5(uniqid($userID, true);               
 }
```